# Can I send an object in a data message (FCM) in android?

Tags: android, push-notification, php-curl

I am developing an android application and using FCM to send data messages using PHP-CURL. I can not find the answer to my question anywhere. Can I send an object through the data message instead of sending just a simple string as a message?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can send an object in body while sending data using PHP. You will have to convert the hashmap with that object to an JsonObject in the frontend. It support both FCM and GCM.